# how to build android framework

Tags: android, frameworks, build

I have tried "mmm" under the path of `frameworks/base`.
But I have never got the result I wanted.
Is there any one who has successfully builded the framework of android?
I think it will make a new `framework.jar` into the path of

```
/out/debug/target/product/{my-phone}/system/framework
```

Can any one help me ?
It is a strange problem .

Comment: are you building generic? i have never tried on framework, though it does work on apps

Comment: I just want to build the path of frameworks/base to get the frameworks.jar and then push it into my mobilephone .

Comment: what is  {my-phone} here? is it generic. If its some thing else i think you need to use mm PRODUCT-{my-phone}-eng . The last part eng depends on the full build , if its user make it user

Comment: I have just tried to use mm PRODUCT  T34hat(the name of my phone).

Comment: mm PRODUCT-T34hat-eng or PRODUCT-T34hat-user or PRODUCT-T34hat-userdebug. It should be one of the above. add hyphen in the middle

Comment: Thanks . I think that's the answer I want. It does make change. But there is an error.Created filesystem with 10/1000 inodes and 1312/4000 blocks
Package target files: out/debug/target/product/f12nad/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/f12nad_debug-target_files-eng.osvup.zip
acp: missing destination file

Answer (score 1):

Try using make instead of mmm. make will not take much time if you have already build the system image..

Answer (score 0):

i usualy use "make -j4" to build Android source, framework.jar will be put in out/target/product/generic/system/framework. In my experience, 'mmm' can not used to build framework, I just use it to build system applications